# Hibernate group by criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

i am new to hibernate. I am using hibernate in my project but i am stuck at one point. I have two database tables which is similar to as follows :

First table

```
Category
id | name
---------
1  | cat1
2  | cat2
```

Second table

```
Product
id | categoryid | name
----------------------
1  | 1          | p1
2  | 1          | p2
```

What i wanted to achieve is to get the resultset containing category and product count in each category.

```
categoryid  |  productcount
1           |  2
2           |  0
```

Currently i am able to do it using Hibernate native sql support.

**SQL :**

```
SELECT c.id, CASE WHEN x.count IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE x.count END AS productcount
FROM category AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT categoryid,count(*) AS count
    FROM product
    GROUP BY categoryid
) AS x
ON x.categoryid = c.id
```

Please help me out to achieve this using hibernate criteria
Thanks

Comment: Are you merely asking how to convert this SQL to Hibernate criteria? HQL / JPQL / criteria (Hibernate or JPA), all of them do not support a sub select statement in either the `JOIN` or `FROM` clause.

Comment: @Tiny  Should i conclude that it's not possible using criteria

Comment: I recommend you to use Spring Data along hibernate, it will make your life much easier. don't waste time on writing such general queries!

Comment: If there does not exist an alternate statement yielding the same result list without requiring a sub select statement in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` clause, then you will have to go only with the native SQL or create a view against the target table logically doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks guys, modifed my query little bit so that i can apply criteria

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use stored procedure and what you want as a result declare it as an OUT parameter . This tutorial will help you to write or call stored procedure in hibernate query
 http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/